# How do I add a button with action to ShowInputAsync from MahApps.Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm using MahApps Metro in a wpf application.  I'm using their ShowInputAsync() [Dialog](http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html).

I'm wanting to save a directory, and I wanted to use a Dialog to set that directory.

So, In my MainWindow.xaml.cs, I have something similar to;

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInputDirectory)) 
{
    userInputDirectory = await this.ShowInputAsync("Your Directory", "Set Your Directory");
}
```

That works well, and I like how the Dialog looks, but I'd like to add a Browse button, so that they don't have to have a directory location memorized, and can just browse to the desired directory using a `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();`

Like I said, I like how it looks now, and I don't want to remove the other two buttons, or replace a button, I'd just like to add one.  Any help is appreciated.

**Edit1**

I created a new User Control, by right clicking on the project -> Add... -> User Control -> User Control (WPF), and changed it from `UserControl` to `Dialogs:BaseMetroDialog`.  I also added the xmlns for Controls.  I'm getting an error `Exception: Cannot create an instance of "BaseMetroDialog"`.  Code is below.

```
<Dialogs:BaseMetroDialog x:Class="testApp.CustomDialog"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         xmlns:Dialogs="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"          
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Dialogs:BaseMetroDialog>
```

My .cs file

```
namespace testApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CustomDialog.xaml
/// </summary>
    public partial class CustomDialog : CustomDialog
    {
        public CustomDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting in the .xaml file is shown in the xaml window before I try to run the program.

```
InnerException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
    StackTrace
         at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,     Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,     RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)

InnerException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        StackTrace
            at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog.HandleTheme()
            at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog.Initialize()
            at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog..ctor()
```

**Edit2**

In case anybody else finds this, and is having the same problem, the MahApps.Metro team (Which is awesome, and very helpful) didn't add CustomDialog fixes until 1.1.3 APHA, and instead of BaseMetroDialog, you should use CustomDialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, metro does not have a browser dialog. 
In order to have that kind of behavior, you'll need to create your own custom metro dialog.

To do so, you'll have to create a new User Control of type CustomDialog (located in MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs) and implement the intended behaviour yourself.

In your custom dialog, add a browser button which calls 
System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();

Once you have your custom control, you can show it using the following code:

```
var browserDialog = new MyCustomDialog();
await this.ShowMetroDialogAsync(browserDialog);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.  I'm going to add an edit to the question to ask you a fairly long winded question about your instructions.

Comment: @kskyriacou I have a similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68537386/1232087)