# Mahapps metro: How to add an extra button to ShowInputAsync() dialog

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

In my `WPF` app I am using [MahApps Metro](https://mahapps.com/) framework. For a test, I am using [ShowInputAsync(...)](https://mahapps.com/api/MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs/DialogManager/573D3CAB) dialog (as shown below) to have user enter product key. I would like to add another button or a link to this dialog so that when a user clicks on that button (or link) the app takes the user to a page that explains how to get a product key. **Question**: How can we add an extra button or link to Mahapps metro's this input dialog?

```
private async void BtnEnterProdKey_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var result = await this.ShowInputAsync("Trail Expired:", "Please enter product key and click ok.");

        if (result == null)
            return;
        else
           {
             //code to process product key
           }
}
```

**Current display of the dialog**

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, in MahApps Metro, you have to create yourself a custom dialog by implementing `Metro.Controls.Dialogs.CustomDialog`. For more information: https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.CustomDialog.Sample